# Calling Custom Fucntions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, function

I'm having trouble I think with calling a custom function using jQuery. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="box" class="red"></div>
```

CSS

```
.red {
    background-color:red;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
}
#box {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
function color() {
    $('#box').delay(2000).toggleClass('red').toggleclass('blue');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    .color();
});
```

I have also tried using $('#box').color(); under document ready. I can't figure out what is wrong. It looks correct to me and is in line with my googling for solutions.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wbndbweo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, remove the dot before function call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    color();
});
```

---

**Next**, you have a typo in `toggleClass` where you should use `camel case` (capital C):

```
function color() {
    $('#box').delay(2000).toggleClass('red').toggleclass('blue');
}
```

---

**Finally**, the `.toggleClass()` function is not queued and can't be delayed with the jQuery `.delay()` function. You could use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#box').toggleClass('red').toggleClass('blue');
},2000);
```

or if you're queuing other things, you can delay `.toggleClass()` by adding it to the queue with the `.queue()` function:

```
$('#box').delay(2000).queue(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red').toggleClass('blue');
});
```

---

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wbndbweo/2/

Comment: Woops. Types aside (due to me changing things around) looks like the delay was messing things up a bit. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

One typo with `toggleClass()` and unnecessary dot before `color()`. Working example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbndbweo/1/)

```
function color() {
    $('#box').delay(2000).toggleClass('red').toggleClass('blue');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    color();
});
```